# Put Information to a picture after Capture Android

Tags: android, storing-information

Good day everyone.I want to put certain information on a picture which have been captured,for example from which location was it captured,in which angle,date of capture and etc.I heard of Id Columns inside android picture but not sure how i make that happen,can anyone please give me an example?

Here is a code how i capture a picture with x,y dimensions(like goggles crop)

```
Thread tGetPic = new Thread( new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            Double[] ratio = getRatio();
                            int left = (int) (ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosX());
                            // 0 is height
                            int top = (int) (ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosY());

                            int right = (int)(ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosX());

                            int bottom = (int)(ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosY());

                            savePhoto(mPreview.getPic(left,top,right,bottom));
                            mAutoFocus = true;




                        } 
                    });
                    tGetPic.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting image you will receive the Intent. Do putExtra to this intent to add the info you want to. And use this in next activty or wherever you need the info.

While calling camera, you call it as

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and you have to override the method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Where **data** is the intent with image. You need to add more info to this intent as follows.

```
data.putExtra("imageId","12456");
data.putExtra("location","paris");
```

Also refer this link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,its my mistake of my info sorry million  times,I'm not using default capture intent,I'm using custom preview and custom capturing,which captures x,y dimensions of image(like goggles crop) so thats the problem i don't have ActivityResult i only have another line of capture code which ill post right now and again thanks a lot for help!

Comment: i figured out with the link above you provided it helped thank you!